# how to count the total_number in between hour's - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table like

```
|Doctor_id | login_hour | logout_hour |
-------   -----------  -----------
 12         10          12
 13         11          13
 14         09          13
 15         13          14
```

I want to know how many doctors is schedule for every hour. If the doctor has schedule between 11 and 13, he should appear in 11th & 12th hour.Kindly let me know how to do this in MySQL

The output should be like

```
Hour | Number_of_doctors
----   -----------------
10         2
11         3
12         2
13         1
```

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code.

Comment: Also, your numbers don't add up. If 13 equals 1, then 12 must equal 2.

Comment: @Strawberry: Sorry. yes, for 12 it should be 2. i am changing it

Answer (score 0):

You can do with inner `SELECT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.login_hour,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM doctors WHERE login_hour <= t.login_hour AND logout_hour 
> t.login_hour) AS number_of_doctors
FROM doctors t
ORDER BY t.login_hour;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b528/2/0)**.

**Update**

This would assume at least one doctor is logged in (as Strawberry has rightly said). If you want the total number of doctors logged in at any given hour then you can use the below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM doctors WHERE login_hour <= ? AND logout_hour > ?;
```

Comment: This assumes that at least one doctor is logged in at any given time.

Comment: @Darshan: The query output seems to be not correct.

Comment: @Strawberry: i want hourly how many expert has been scheduled.

Comment: @PraveenReddy See comments above.

Comment: Also, except where a result is 0 or NULL, I tend to think that if the answer doesn't match the desired output, then it's probably either wrong, or at best incomplete.

Comment: @DarshanMehta: can its possible with case's in mysql ?

Comment: @Strawberry: can its possible with case's in mysql ?

Comment: There are two doctors logged in at 12

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea - but as stated in comments, I'd actually handle the bulk of this in application code...

```
SELECT x.hour
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM
     ( SELECT  9 hour UNION 
       SELECT 10 UNION
       SELECT 11 UNION
       SELECT 12 UNION
       SELECT 13 UNION
       SELECT 14 
     ) x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON x.hour >= y.login_hour 
   AND x.hour < y.logout_hour
 GROUP
    BY hour;
```

Comment: Problem is if doctor works for example from 22:00 to 02:00

Comment: @OtoShavadze Yes. Time is linear. Sic transit gloria mundi.